# RDD creating adjacency list

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create adj list with input

```
RDD=["2\t{'3': 1}",
     "3\t{'2': 2}",
     "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
     "5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
     "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}",
     "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "10\t{'5': 1}",
     "11\t{'5': 2}"]
```

expectation is adj list should creates a new record for any dangling nodes and sets it edges (neighbors) to be a empty
initializes a rank of 1/N for each node
I am writing a spark job to read in the raw data but i need to initialize an adjacency list representation with a record for each node (including dangling nodes).
Returns: RDD -  a pair RDD of (node_id , (score, edges))
I am not fully there yet but I am trying to do the following.

```
adj_list = ()
ad = sc.broadcast(adj_list)
# write any helper functions here
def parse(line):
    node, edges = line.split('\t')
    print(f'node: {node} edges: {edges}')
    for key, value in ast.literal_eval(edges):
        yield (node, key, value)
    
RDD = dataRDD.flatMap(parse) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[1]+y[1], x[0],y[0]))
```

1. I am getting error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when I do collect. I looked around and dont have a clue on what’s happening.
2. am I going in the right direction? Idea is to add the scores then at the end divide it by total node count
3. by the way i need to return rdd with the expected return data
   Appreciate guiding me in the logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does something similar.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import ast

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

RDD=["2\t{'3': 1}",
     "3\t{'2': 2}",
     "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
     "5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
     "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}",
     "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
     "10\t{'5': 1}",
     "11\t{'5': 2}"]



columns =["raw_string"]

RDD = [Row(ele) for ele in RDD]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(RDD)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=rdd1, schema=columns)

print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=20, truncate=False)

df2 = df1.withColumn('id', split(df1['raw_string'], '\t').getItem(0)) \
       .withColumn('mapping_string', split(df1['raw_string'], '\t').getItem(1)) \

print("df2 dataframe")
df2.show(n=20, truncate=False)

schema = MapType(StringType(),LongType())


def rowudf(mapping_str):
    print("mapping_str", mapping_str)
    print("type of mapping_str", type(mapping_str))
    given_dict = ast.literal_eval(mapping_str)
    print("converted dictionary", given_dict)
    print("keys here", given_dict.keys())
    print("values here", given_dict.values())
    print("type of dictionary", type(given_dict))
    return given_dict

udfValue = udf(rowudf, schema)
intermediate_df = df2.withColumn("mapping_dict", udfValue(F.col("mapping_string")))

print("intermediate_df dataframe")
intermediate_df.show(n=20, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+---------------------------+
|raw_string                 |
+---------------------------+
|2\t{'3': 1}                |
|3\t{'2': 2}                |
|4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |
|5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|
|6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |
|7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|10\t{'5': 1}               |
|11\t{'5': 2}               |
+---------------------------+

df2 dataframe
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+
|raw_string                 |id |mapping_string          |
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+
|2\t{'3': 1}                |2  |{'3': 1}                |
|3\t{'2': 2}                |3  |{'2': 2}                |
|4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |4  |{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |
|5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|5  |{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|
|6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |6  |{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |
|7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |7  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |8  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |9  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |
|10\t{'5': 1}               |10 |{'5': 1}                |
|11\t{'5': 2}               |11 |{'5': 2}                |
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+

intermediate_df dataframe
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+------------------------+
|raw_string                 |id |mapping_string          |mapping_dict            |
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+------------------------+
|2\t{'3': 1}                |2  |{'3': 1}                |{3 -> 1}                |
|3\t{'2': 2}                |3  |{'2': 2}                |{2 -> 2}                |
|4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |4  |{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |{1 -> 1, 2 -> 1}        |
|5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|5  |{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|{2 -> 1, 4 -> 3, 6 -> 1}|
|6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |6  |{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |{5 -> 2, 2 -> 1}        |
|7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |7  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{5 -> 1, 2 -> 1}        |
|8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |8  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{5 -> 1, 2 -> 1}        |
|9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |9  |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{5 -> 1, 2 -> 1}        |
|10\t{'5': 1}               |10 |{'5': 1}                |{5 -> 1}                |
|11\t{'5': 2}               |11 |{'5': 2}                |{5 -> 2}                |
+---------------------------+---+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am looking for answers for those questions. Appreciate it